# how can we fetch the integer value from the give array

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how I can select a value from an array given a key.

```
array(1) { 
   [0]=> string(11) "INTEGER: 72" 
}
array(1) { 
   [0]=> string(12) "INTEGER: 634" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$integer_arr = [];
foreach ( $columns as $value) { 
   $integer_arr[]  = str_replace("INTEGER: ", "", $value);
}
```

$integer_arr will be your arrays of Integers.

Comment: You should elaborate on your code so the poster actually knows how things work.
Just giving the solution won't teach him anything.

Answer (score 1):

An array is a dataset of given values (and/or keys).
In order to select the values, you can use `$array_value = $array['key'];` which will return the value.

Tip: use `var_dump($array);`

Check out this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

If I misunderstood your question and you want to select the integer in the string values of your arrays, you can use this:

`$value = intval(str_replace('INTEGER', $array[0]));`

This will first remove the string and then turn the array value into an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You can simply break a string with a separator `:`

```
foreach($array as $a)
{
   $explode = explode(": ",$a);
   echo $explode[1];
}
```

You can also store it in a separate array like this

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $a)
{
   $explode = explode(": ",$a);
   $new_array[] = $explode[1];
}
```

Here is the live [demo](https://3v4l.org/uUhc2). For the reference you can visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)